# Linq / Lambda Expressions / Delegates - What's the best explanation you've seen on this?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm interested in knowing where you have found the best, clearest and/or simplest explanation of the various technologies used in Linq, such as Lambda's, delegates etc. There are many books available on this subject, but I am looking for some source that goes into painstakingly great detail to make the subject as simple as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Skeet, [C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/AboutBook.aspx). Buy a copy for every room in your house.

Comment: This book is good, but now it is a little dated - it doesn't even include C# 4.

Answer (score 3):

I got some good comments on a blog post I did a little over a year ago:

[Loops, Conversions and Lambdas](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2008/12/15/loops-conversions-and-lambdas.aspx)

It's definitely not "painstakingly detailed", but it shows how the .NET runtime as evolved from delegates, to anonymous methods and finally, lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

[Functional-programming-in-Csharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375166/Functional-programming-in-Csharp) is a very good article on functional programming, delegates and Lambda Expression.

For me it was simple,nice and pretty straight forward. Most of the things can be understood looking into the examples itself. Very well explained.